# Got an 404 error When request to paypal in express in firebase function

Tags: firebase, paypal, google-cloud-functions, localhost, paypal-sandbox

**Update02**

Below is my emulator screenshot. and I try to post request with the url like `http://localhost:5001/wecount-9c03c/us-central1/payment/paypal-generate-link` with insomnia.
[image]

I got a 404 error like below.

```
Error: {"message":"Request failed with status code 404","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 404\n at createError (/Users/dean/Documents/workspace/wecount/functions/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n at settle (/Users/dean/Documents/workspace/wecount/functions/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/dean/Documents/workspace/wecount/functions/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)\n at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:390:22)\n at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1307:12)\n at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)","config":{"url":"https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals","method":"post","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer token","User-Agent":"axios/0.21.1","host":"api-m.sandbox.paypal.com"},"proxy":{"host":"localhost","port":5001},"params":{"tracking_id":"TEST_TRACK_ID","preferred_language_code":"en-US","partner_config_override":{"return_url":"http://local.test.com:5000","return_url_description":"the url to return the merchant after the paypal onboarding process."},"operations":[{"operation":"API_INTEGRATION","api_integration_preference":{"rest_api_integration":{"integration_method":"PAYPAL","integration_type":"THIRD_PARTY","third_party_details":{"features":["PAYMENT","REFUND"]}}}}],"legal_consents":[{"type":"SHARE_DATA_CONSENT","granted":true}],"products":["EXPRESS_CHECKOUT"]},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1}}
```

**Update01**

I'm composing paypal functions with createApp function, then calling it like below.

```
// app.ts

import * as Paypal from './paypal';

import express, {Express} from 'express';

import cors from 'cors';

export const createApp = (): Express => {
  const app = express();
  app.use(cors({origin: true}));

  app.get('/', (_, res) => {
    res.send('It works');
  });

  app.post('/paypal-get-accessToken', (_, res) => {
    Paypal.getAccessToken()
      .then((response) => res.send(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`))
      .catch((err) => res.send(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`));
  });

  app.post('/paypal-generate-link', (req, res) => {
    Paypal.generateLink()
      .then((response) => res.send(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`))
      .catch((err) => res.send(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`));
  });

  return app;
};


// index.ts
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import {createApp} from './src/app';

admin.initializeApp();

const app = createApp();

export const payment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I've been trying to request Paypal api with express in firebase function.
But I got a 404 error in localhost even though I works well in postman with same headers and payload. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Here is my code. And I call this function with http `onRequest` method in firebase.

```js
export const generateLink = async (
  resquestBody: Record<string, any> | null = null,
): Promise<any> => {
  const result = await axios({
    url: 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${config.paypal.access_token}`,
    },
    params: resquestBody ?? requestBodyEx,
    proxy: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5001,
    },
  });

  return result;
};

//app.ts
 app.post('/paypal-generate-link', (req, res) => {
    Paypal.generateLink()
      .then((response) => res.send(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`))
      .catch((err) => res.send(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`));
 });
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to call the Cloud function from localhost?

Comment: Wouldn't the 404 be coming from the proxy rather than Paypal itself?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I updated my code. :)

Comment: @samthecodingman I can't know where the errors are coming from.

Comment: Can you share the URL that you get after deploying the cloud function? Just remove the project ID.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I cannot deploy this functions yet because I have spark plan. I tested this function only in firebase emulator. This project I've tried is open-source. you can check my PR here. https://github.com/wecount-dev/wecount/pull/82 . Thanks

Comment: When you make a post request at `app.post('/paypal-generate-link')` the domain for this request will be `localhost:port` where your website is running and not the cloud function. If you are using Cloud functions then you should fetch the complete URL from the emulator... Can you open logs tab in emulator and share a screenshot so we can see the URL?

Comment: @Dharmaraj updated it. :)

Comment: Did `app.post('https://localhost:5001/wecount-9c03c/us-central1/payment/paypal-generate-link')` instead of just `app.post('/paypal-generate-link')` work ? Logs seem to be good

Comment: I did it, but got an 400 error.

Comment: Then that's something in your function but at least the original issue is resolved and function is running :)

Comment: but.. I got a same error text without error code from 404 to 400. When I try to request to paypal api without cloud function just direct with insomnia, There is no erros. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is running on `http://localhost:3000` then `app.post('/paypal-generate-link')` will make a request at `http://localhost:3000/paypal-generate-link` instead of your Cloud function. You should specify complete URL when making requests to external APIs.

```js
app.post('https://localhost:5001/wecount-9c03c/us-central1/payment/paypal-generate-link')
```

You would have to replace localhost with production URL once your deploy cloud functions to Firebase.

```
export const payment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This will create a function endpoint at `https://<cloud-function-url>/wecount-9c03c/us-central1/payment`. Then to access any endpoint that you specify, just append that at the end for example `/paypal-generate-link`

Comment: But when I try to get a access token with `/paypal-get-accessToken`, It works well with this url `http://localhost:5001/wecount-9c03c/us-central1/payment/paypal-get-accessToken` in insomnia.

Comment: @dean you'll have to specify complete URLs in Axios on frontend in all requests.